# How to improve Rails query to reject current user items in the list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record-query

I have a query that will fetch the all images and filter the current user uploaded, rated and favorite images. But this is consuming more time. Please see below query and suggest a best query to reduce execution time.

```
@images = Image.active_images.order('images_order')
          .where.not(user_id: current_user.id)
          .select{|item| item.ratings.where(user_id: current_user.id).count <= 0 }
          .select{|item| item.favorite_images.where(user_id: current_user.id).count <= 0 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could start by getting rid of N+1 queries. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html .

preloading associations you use will significantly decrease your execution time.

An even bigger boost would be to do all of this in one query by using AREL or pure SQL.

A possible solution:

```
Image.active_images.joins(:ratings, :favorite_images)
          .where.not(user_id: current_user.id)
          .where.not(ratings: { user_id: current_user.id})
          .where.not(favorite_images: { user_id: current_user.id })
          .distinct #Joining has_many associations might duplicate the image records in your select, so use distinct
          .order(:images_order)
```

Comment: `joins`  will do `INNER JOIN` by default so it will only load `Image` which has `ratings` and `favourite_images`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale yes you are true

Comment: @AnjankumarHN if you are using Rails 5 and want outer joins instead, you can use `left_outer_joins` instead of `joins`. If you have rails < 5, then you have to write in sql ( `joins('ratings ON images.id = ratings.image_id')`) or Arel.